# How do I make a masterpiece Mach car in Grand Prix Story?

Tags: grand-prix-story

I've levelled up my mechanics in both of my groups in Grand Prix Story to level 5.  I've levelled up the Dragster and it's follow-ons to get to the Mach car.  Sadly, when I try to build one, my groups complain that "it won't be perfect" and, as predicted, it generally isn't.  Currently, my groups make much better Aero cars.  Their efforts at making Mach cars indicate stats that are usually lower than the expected levels by double digits.

Should I be selecting different mechanics?  Or do I have the wrong drivers?  Do I have to optimize my groups to this level in order to make a masterpiece car?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Car construction and part installation are based off of the Tech stat.  The higher it is, the better you will do.  Mechanics will gain tech (and other) stats slowly, at random intervals.

I think to make a decent Mach car is somewhere around 400 Tech.  The simplest way to do this is to heavily weight one of your teams towards the tech stat.  Train the driver almost exclusively for Tech.  Fire those mechanics that have the lowest tech stat, and hire ones that are higher.

In a pinch, if you can't hire any decent tech mechanics, an aura (in order of lowest to highest strength: blue, purple, white, gold) will also help you during construction.  Those are one-shot deals, though, so be careful.